# Whats the diffrence between an array<Byte>^ and a byte*?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, managed-c++

And is it possible to cast the array< Byte>^ to an byte*?

how would the below code need to changed to return a byte*?

```
array<Byte>^ StrToByteArray(System::String^ unicodeString)
{
    UTF8Encoding^ utf8 = gcnew UTF8Encoding;
    array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = utf8->GetBytes( unicodeString );
    return encodedBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array^ is a handle to an object in the managed heap, byte* is a pointer to an unmanaged byte. You cannot cast between them, but it is possible to fix the managed array and obtain a pointer to the elements within it.

**EDIT** in response to first comment:

Here's a code sample taken from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on msdn

The bit you are most interested in is the void Load() method. Here they are pinning the array, and taking a pointer to the first element in it...

```
// pin_ptr_1.cpp
// compile with: /clr 
using namespace System;
#define SIZE 10

#pragma unmanaged
// native function that initializes an array
void native_function(byte* p) {
    for(byte i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        p[i] = i;
}
#pragma managed

public ref class A {
private:
    array<byte>^ arr;   // CLR integer array

public:
    A() {
        arr = gcnew array<byte>(SIZE);
    }

    void load() {
        pin_ptr<byte> p = &arr[0];   // pin pointer to first element in arr
        byte* np = p;   // pointer to the first element in arr
        native_function(np);   // pass pointer to native function
    }

    int sum() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++)
            total += arr[i];
        return total;
    }
};

int main() {
    A^ a = gcnew A;
    a->load();   // initialize managed array using the native function
    Console::WriteLine(a->sum());
}
```

Comment: would you be able to give an excample of such a fix?

Comment: This is for Visual Studio 2003. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the link for Visual Studio 2005 and more, which uses `pin_ptr` (`__pin` is no longer supported)

Comment: I amended the post with the updated example + link, thank you for pointing out my error :)

Comment: i tried your excample and change it to fit mine but it seems like your excample just creates an int from the array. am i correct saying a byte* is an array of bytes as well? (byte* InpData = new byte[255]; i got this piece of code where i am excpecting the byte* before i call the method i added to the question and which gets sent to an exteran dll.) How would i need to change the code in the question to get to return a byte*?

Comment: byte* is just a pointer to a byte. If the byte it is pointing at is the first element in an array of bytes, then you could say it is a pointer to an array. Using pointer arithmetic you can increment the pointer over all the array elements.. I'll update the example a little more.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot cast it, but array has a method that returns the raw array called "data()"

EDIT: nvm, thought you were talking about the stl class array.

Comment: it tells me that 'data' : is not a member of 'System::Array'.