# Can you UTF8Encode a System::String^ to a Byte*?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the diffrence between an array<Byte>^ and a byte*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948186/whats-the-diffrence-between-an-arraybyte-and-a-byte)

i am translating some c# code to c++ however translating the piece about UTF8Encoding, i get stuck that c++ returns a array^ while i need a byte* as areturn type. I spend a long time on this code trying to get around it but i keep failing. How could i change it to return a byte*?

```
array<Byte>^ StrToByteArray(System::String^ unicodeString)
{
    UTF8Encoding^ utf8 = gcnew UTF8Encoding;
    array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = utf8->GetBytes( unicodeString );
    return encodedBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to do a conversion from array to X* without manually copying each element. This would look something like following snippet:

```
byte* StrToByteArray(System::String^ unicodeString)
{
    UTF8Encoding^ utf8 = gcnew UTF8Encoding;
    array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = utf8->GetBytes( unicodeString );
    const size_t len = encodedBytes->Length;
    byte* encodedBytesRaw = new byte[len+1];
    for( int i=0; i<len; ++i )
        encodedBytesRaw[i] = encodedBytes[i];
    encodedBytesRaw [len]=0;
    return encodedBytesRaw;
}
```

The caller has to delete the returned byte array, once he is finished with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i had to make 3 changes to the code to make it work, you forgot one ; in the for and you are using bytes and not byte. the line byte[len]=0; still comes up with errors but everything seems fine when i leave it out. what was the use of it here?

Comment: @Andy: i fixed it, that was a safety measure, because i dont know if utf->GetBytes returns null-terminated data. So its added a zero-byte just to be safe (if the documentation of GetBytes says that it returns zero-terminated data, feel free to omit that line).

Comment: The input string may contain null-characters, and these will be encoded as code units of value `0x00` in UTF8.